# Update the value from table in textbox BUT not updated the value in db?

Tags: php, textbox, updates

I have listed all the data(Item, Category, Job, Hole(Hole is evaluating marks)) and I display the Hole(mark) in textbox filed.

I want to update the Hole(marks) after user change.

I list all the data using php

```
<?php
try{
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gcmes", "root", "");
$sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM details");

echo"<table class='info' align='center'>";
echo"<tr><td width='10'><b>No</b></td>
<td width='30'><b>Category</b></td>
<td width='50'><b>Job</b></td>
<td width='40'><b>Evaluate</b></td><tr>";
foreach($sql as $row) {
$Item = $row["Item"];
$Category = $row["Category"];
$Job = $row["Job"];
$Evaluate = $row["Hole 1"];

echo'
    <tr>
        <td>' . $Item . '</td>
        <td>' . $Category . '</td>
        <td>' . $Job . '</td>
        <td><input type="input" name="Evaluate" id="Evaluate" value="' . $Evaluate . '">
        </td>
    </tr>
';
}
echo"</table></form>";

if(isset($_POST['Update_btn'])){
$Evaluate = $_POST["Hole 1"];

if(empty(Evaluate)){
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Please fill in the required fields to update!')</script>";
}

else{
$insert=$con->prepare("UPDATE details SET Evaluate=:Hole 1 WHERE Item=:Item");
$insert->bindParam(':Hole1',$Evaluate);
$insert->bindParam(":Item",$Item);
$insert->execute();

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successful Updated ! ');
window.location.href = 'Hole 1.php';
</script>";
}//else
}//if add button
}//try
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "error".$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

The html code i just use to display button

```
<form id="form1" name="Hole 1" method="post" action="Hole 1.php">
<input name="Update_btn" type="image" id="Update_btn" onmouseover="this.src='UpdateO.png'" onmouseout="this.src='UpdateD.png'" value="submit" src="UpdateD.png" alt="submit Button" align="right"> 
</form>
```

**The problem is will alert message successful updated BUT the value not update in my db. Why? what is the problem?**

[image]
this is my interface
i want update the marks in textbox filed

**I need to change the hole as a selection give the user choose which hole that need to update only, i set the hole have a drop-down menu list. How to dectect which hole?**

[image]

i just add the code after `<td>{$rowData['Frequency']}</td>` (dn Fer answer)

```
<td><select name="hole">
    <option value="Hole1">1</option>
    <option value="Hole2">2</option>
    <option value="Hole3">3</option>
    <option value="Hole4">4</option>
    <option value="Hole5">5</option>
    <option value="Hole6">6</option>
    <option value="Hole7">7</option>
    <option value="Hole8">8</option>
    <option value="Hole9">9</option>
    <option value="Hole10">10</option>
    <option value="Hole11">11</option>
    <option value="Hole12">12</option>
    <option value="Hole13">13</option>
    <option value="Hole14">14</option>
    <option value="Hole15">15</option>
    <option value="Hole16">16</option>
    <option value="Hole17">17</option>
    <option value="Hole18">18</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Whats is the error you actually get? (And it might help to ident the code in your question)

Comment: The error is `Notice: Undefined index: Hole 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\gcmes\Hole 1.php on line 233`

Comment: "Hole 1" is the name of the form which is never sent as part of the POST data. Therefor `$_POST["Hole 1"]` does not exists.

Comment: So, how can I POST data ?

Comment: In php: `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: change this `$Evaluate = $_POST["Hole 1"];` to `$Evaluate = var_dump($_POST);` ?

Comment: No. var_dump is a php function which prints variables to the output. I've read your question in the comment wrong. You post data with elements within the form. Like input, textarea, checkbox, etc. Values of them are posted to php. Take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_forms.asp

Comment: Sorry, actually how can I do? I take look the link, but not very understand what are u and that saying?

Comment: Then I guess you're in way over your head. That site shows transferring form data to php data. If you don't understand it, I suggest looking for beginner tutorials on using html form and php.

Comment: Ohh, maybe I misunderstanding you say. So now what is my coding problem?

Comment: You've named the form "Hole 1" instead of the input. Add a name attribute to the input with "Hole 1" as value

Comment: Still cannot update

Comment: Then update your question, code and errors so I can take another look.

Comment: I have updated my problem but doesn't have shown any error, but the value not updated in my db

Comment: Ok. Different approach since you're knowledge isn't adequate... I'll post new code the way I think it should be and we go on from there. Might take some time since it's weekend.

Comment: Very thank you, Yes I just new to php. Thanks a lot. I will be waiting for you. Happy weekend.

Comment: Just to be clear... do you want an update button for each single row or an update button for all the rows at once?

Comment: i want update button for all the row at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the following in mind:

- I don't have the same environment as yours, so it might not work one
  on one.
- Spaces in database fieldNames and arrayKeys, etc. are discouraged. I
  prefer to use lowerCamelCase, check if dB fieldNames match the code
  below!
- Read the comments I've placed in the code.
- I didn't take psr coding, value validation or safety (sql injection), etc. in consideration. The code is to guide you, you should take these things in consideration yourself.

Hopefully getting you closer to your goals...

**Update: The values of the Evaluate field of each row is now validated to be an integer in the range from 1 to 5.**

```
<?php

//Initialize variables
$result     = '';
$doUpdate   = isset($_POST['updateButton_x']);

//Because button type is 'image', we get parameters buttonName_x and buttonName_y
//from the browsers POST request when the form is sent.
if ($doUpdate) { 
    //Update button pressed.
    //Initialize variables
    $stmtSetParams = $stmtInParams = array();
    $validationOptions = array('options' => array('min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 5));
    //Define statement and parameters (Assuming dB field 'item' is the primary key).
    $set = '`hole1` = CASE `item` ';
    foreach ($_POST['evaluate'] as $item => $hole1) {
        //Get input value of each table row
        if (filter_var($hole1, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $validationOptions) !== false) {
            //Field is not blank
            $set .= 'WHEN ? THEN ? ';
            $stmtSetParams[] = $stmtInParams[] = $item;
            $stmtSetParams[] = $hole1;
        } else {
            //Field is not an integer from 1 to 5
            $result .= "Field \'Evaluate\' of item \'$item\' with a value of \'$hole1\' is not from 1 to 5 and skipped while saving!\\n";
        }
    }
    $set .= 'END';
    //Define query placeholders
    $placeHolders = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($stmtInParams), '?'));
    $query = <<<SQL
UPDATE `details` SET $set WHERE `item` IN ($placeHolders)
SQL;
}

//Query the dB.
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gcmes', 'root');
    if ($doUpdate) {
        //Update requested. Prepare and execute update query
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array_merge($stmtSetParams, $stmtInParams));
        $result .= 'Update Completed!';
    }
    //Query for en fetch (updated) table data
    $stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM `details`");
    $tableData = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    //A PDO exception is raised
    $result = 'Error: ' . addslashes($e->getMessage());
}

//Alert results of database operations
if ($result != '') {
    echo "<script>alert('$result')</script>";
}
?>

<form id="form1" name="chooseFormNameIfNeeded" method="post" action="test.php">
    <!--  attribute align is deprecated, define and use a class instead -->
    <table class="info align-center">
        <tr>
            <!--  use th instead of td for table header -->
            <!--  using <b> tag is discouraged -->
            <th width="10"><b>No</b></th>
            <th width="30"><b>Category</b></th>
            <th width="50"><b>Job</b></th>
            <th width="40"><b>Evaluate</b></th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            foreach ($tableData as $rowData) {
                //Print a table row for each of the fetched records
                echo <<<HTML
<tr>
    <td>{$rowData['item']}</td>
    <td>{$rowData['category']}</td>
    <td>{$rowData['job']}</td>
    <td>
        <!-- Assuming dB field 'item' is the primary key. -->
        <input type="number" name="evaluate[{$rowData['item']}]" id="Evaluate" value="{$rowData['hole1']}"
               min=1 max=5
        >
    </td>
</tr>
HTML;
            }
        ?>
    </table>
    <!--  Attribute align is deprecated, define and use a class instead -->
    <!--  Value attribute should not be specified -->
    <input name="updateButton" type="image" id="Update_btn" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x50/0000FF?text=Update" 
           alt="submit Button" class="align-right" 
           onmouseover="this.src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x50/00FF00?text=Update'"
           onmouseout="this.src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x50/0000FF?text=Update'"
    >
</form>
```

Comment: Your code is achieved my goal. Can I set to the user just can insert number and the number is only between 1 to 5? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I've added the validation. Please mark the question as answered by my code. If you have other questions, you should ask them a separate question. Issues or questions about this code can be discussed over here.

Comment: Ya. I get It.Thank you very much for your help. Maybe later I need to add-on the requirement and will post at here also.

Comment: No problem. Glad to have helped you out.

Comment: hi, if I want to set hole as a drop-down menu list can? because i have 18 hole

Comment: @dnFec  I want to set hole1 as a drop-down menu list to give user choose, how i change it?

Comment: You should ask it as a new question. Site policy.

Comment: @dnFec i have ask new question this is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445034/how-to-get-column-name-and-insert-into-db-after-selecting-name-from-drop-down-li). Can you help me? Pls..