# how to get column name and insert into db after selecting name from drop-down list in php

Tags: php, mysql

How to get the value from a drop-down menu list to insert value in db?

My system has 18 holes, users can update the hole value data according to their needs. So how to detect select which hole and update the data in my db?

This is the code

```
<?php
$result     = '';
$doUpdate   = isset($_POST['updateButton_x']);
if ($doUpdate) { 

$stmtSetParams = $stmtInParams = array();
$validationOptions = array('options' => array('min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 5));
//Define statement and parameters (Assuming dB field 'item' is the primary key).
$set = '`Hole1` = CASE `Item` ';
foreach ($_POST['Evaluate'] as $Item => $Hole1) {
    //Get input value of each table row
    if (filter_var($Hole1, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $validationOptions) !== false) {
        //Field is not blank
        $set .= 'WHEN ? THEN ? ';
        $stmtSetParams[] = $stmtInParams[] = $Item;
        $stmtSetParams[] = $Hole1;
    } else {
        //Field is not an integer from 1 to 5
        $result .= "Field \'Evaluate\' of item \'$Item\' with a value of \'$Hole1\' is not from 1 to 5 and skipped while saving!\\n";
    }
}
$set .= 'END';
//Define query placeholders
$placeHolders = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($stmtInParams), '?'));
$query = <<<SQL
UPDATE `details` SET $set WHERE `Item` IN ($placeHolders)
SQL;
}
//Query the dB.
try {
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gcmes', 'root');
if ($doUpdate) {
    //Update requested. Prepare and execute update query
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array_merge($stmtSetParams, $stmtInParams));
    $result .= 'Update Completed!';
}
//Query for en fetch (updated) table data
$stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM `details`");
$tableData = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
//A PDO exception is raised
$result = 'Error: ' . addslashes($e->getMessage());
}
//Alert results of database operations
if ($result != '') {
echo "<script>alert('$result')</script>";
}
?>
<form id="form1" name="chooseFormNameIfNeeded" method="post" action="Job.php">
<!--  attribute align is deprecated, define and use a class instead -->
<table class="info" align="center">
    <tr>
        <!--  use th instead of td for table header -->
        <!--  using <b> tag is discouraged -->
        <th width="10"><b>Item</b></th>
        <th width="100"><b>Category</b></th>
        <th width="100"><b>Job</b></th>
        <th width="30"><b>Frequency</b></th>
        <th width="10"><b>Hole</b></th>
        <th width="30"><b>Evaluate</b></th>
    </tr>
     <?php
        foreach ($tableData as $rowData) {
            //Print a table row for each of the fetched records
            echo <<<HTML
                echo <<<HTML
        <tr>
            <td>{$rowData['Item']}</td>
            <td>{$rowData['Category']}</td>
            <td>{$rowData['Job']}</td>
            <td>{$rowData['Frequency']}</td>
            <td><select name="hole">
            <option value="Hole1">1</option>
            <option value="Hole2">2</option>
            <option value="Hole3">3</option>
            <option value="Hole4">4</option>
            <option value="Hole5">5</option>
            <option value="Hole6">6</option>
            <option value="Hole7">7</option>
            <option value="Hole8">8</option>
            <option value="Hole9">9</option>
            <option value="Hole10">10</option>
            <option value="Hole11">11</option>
            <option value="Hole12">12</option>
            <option value="Hole13">13</option>
            <option value="Hole14">14</option>
            <option value="Hole15">15</option>
            <option value="Hole16">16</option>
            <option value="Hole17">17</option>
            <option value="Hole18">18</option>
            </select>
        <td>
    <!-- Assuming dB field 'item' is the primary key. -->
    <input type="number" name="Evaluate[{$rowData['Item']}]" id="Evaluate" value="{$rowData['Hole1']}"
           min=1 max=5>
</td>
</tr>
HTML;
}
?>
    </table>
```

User can choose any hole to insert the marks
[image]
Hole is one of the column in my db
[image]
 Anyone please help, thank you!

Comment: You need to use an array name for `hole` like `name="hole[{$rowData['Item']}]"` just like you do for `Evaluate` input.

Comment: Databases have tables . Tables have columns. Tables in relational databases adhere to rules of normalisation. You appear to have a spreadsheet, which is a different thing entirely.

Comment: @Barmar okay, but how to put my value?`value="{$rowData['Hole1']}"` Change it to what?

Comment: You add the `SELECTED` attribute to the `<option>` element whose value matches `$rowData['Hole1']`